Customizing Gantt Charts: Row Height, Arrow Shift, and Task Connections
a: How can I control the height of the row of days?
b: How can I shift the arrow to the left?
c: How can I connect 'task 2' to 'task 1'?

CODE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{ganttchart}[
        x unit=.189cm,
        y unit title=.5cm,
        y unit chart=.6cm,
        hgrid=true,
        time slot format=isodate,
        title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
        title height=1,
        bar/.append style={fill=green!90},
        bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
        group height=.3,
        group peaks height=.2,
        bar incomplete/.append style={fill=green!40},
        time slot format/start date=2024-10-01
        ]{2024-10-01}{2024-11-30}
        \gantttitlecalendar{year} \\
        \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\
        \gantttitlecalendar[
            title label node/.append style={rotate=0},
            title label text =\scalebox{0.3}{\strut#1}
            ]{day} \\
        \ganttset{progress label text={},
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=black!40},
            group/.append style={draw=black, fill=black!80},}
        \ganttgroup{Aim 1}{2024-10-02}{2024-11-02} \\
        \ganttbar[progress=100, name=a]{task 1}{2024-10-02}{2024-10-03} \\
        \ganttbar[progress=100, name=b]{task 2}{2024-10-02}{2024-10-03} \\
        \ganttgroup{Aim 2}{2024-10-03}{2024-11-10} \\
        \ganttbar[progress=80, name=c]{task 3}{2024-10-03}{2024-10-19}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \ganttlink[]{a}{c}
    \end{ganttchart}

\end{document}

OUTPUT:



With title height=0.5 in the option of \gantttitlecalendar[title height=0.5]{day}.
With link bulge=1.3 p.42 in the documentation.
The third point 3rd point was more delicate for me. To create a new link, I used the command \newganttlinktype{<type>}{<TikZ code>} p. 43. Maybe it's simpler, I've never used pgfgantt.

Code
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\newganttlinktype{H}{
%   \ganttsetstartanchor{east}
%   \ganttsetendanchor{east}
  \draw [/pgfgantt/link] (\xLeft,\yUpper) -- ++(\ganttvalueof{x unit}*\ganttvalueof{link bulge},0);
}
\begin{document}

    \begin{ganttchart}[
        x unit=.189cm,
        y unit title=.5cm,
        y unit chart=.6cm,
        hgrid=true,
        time slot format=isodate,
        title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
        title height=1,
        bar/.append style={fill=green!90},
        bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
        group height=.3,
        group peaks height=.2,
        bar incomplete/.append style={fill=green!40},
        time slot format/start date=2024-10-01,
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%
        link bulge=1.3
        ]{2024-10-01}{2024-11-30}
        \gantttitlecalendar{year} \\
        \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\
        \gantttitlecalendar[
            title height=0.5,
            title label node/.append style={rotate=0},
            title label text =\scalebox{0.3}{#1}
            ]{day} \\
        \ganttset{progress label text={},
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=black!40},
            group/.append style={draw=black, fill=black!80},}
        \ganttgroup{Aim 1}{2024-10-02}{2024-11-02} \\
        \ganttbar[progress=100, name=a]{task 1}{2024-10-02}{2024-10-03} \\
        \ganttbar[progress=100, name=b]{task 2}{2024-10-02}{2024-10-03} \\
        \ganttgroup{Aim 2}{2024-10-03}{2024-11-10} \\
        \ganttbar[progress=80, name=c]{task 3}{2024-10-03}{2024-10-19}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \ganttlink[]{a}{c}
        \ganttlink[link/.style={-},link type=H]{b}{a}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}



thank a lot pascal again :)

You're welcome.
